# how can run mongoose query in forEach loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

can anyone help me for how can run mongoose query in forEach loop in nodejs and suggest for inner join result need of both collections

like below details

```
userSchema.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;
    users.forEach(function(u,i){
        var users = [];
        jobSchema.find({u_sno:s.u.sno}, function(err, j) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!u) {
                res.end(JSON.stringify({
                    status: 'failed:Auction not found.',
                    error_code: '404'
                }));
                console.log("User not found.");
                return 
            }
            users.push(j);
        })
    })
    res.send(JSON.stringify({status:"success",message:"successfully done",data:{jobs:j,users:u}}));
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
db.collection.find(query).forEach(function(err, doc) {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: I have gain an error is: **.forEach is not a function**. Why?

Comment: because foreach is a native mongodb function not a mongoose function

Answer (score 14):

Schema.find() is an async function. So your last line of code will execute while you wait for the first job search is executed in your loop. I suggest change it to Promises and use Promise.all(array).

To do so, first you have to change to use Promise with mongoose. you can do this with bluebird like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

Then you can use Promises instead of callbacks like this:

```
userSchema.find({}).then(function(users) {
  var jobQueries = [];

  users.forEach(function(u) {
    jobQueries.push(jobSchema.find({u_sno:s.u.sno}));
  });

  return Promise.all(jobQueries );
}).then(function(listOfJobs) {
    res.send(listOfJobs);
}).catch(function(error) {
    res.status(500).send('one of the queries failed', error);
});
```

**EDIT** How to list both jobs and users

If you want to have a structure like:

```
[{ 
  user: { /* user object */,
  jobs: [ /* jobs */ ]
}]
```

you could merge the lists together. listOfJobs is in the same order as the jobQueries list, so they are in the same order as the users. Save users to a shared scope to get access to the list in the 'then function' and then merge.

```
..
}).then(function(listOfJobs) {
  var results = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < listOfJobs.length; i++) {
    results.push({
      user: users[i],
      jobs: listOfJobs[i]
    });
  }

  res.send(results);
}).catch(function(error) {
  res.status(500).send('one of the queries failed', error);
});
```

Comment: thank for help but i have one question that how can print both list of jobs and users

Comment: show this error---->App Started on PORT 8080
express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead App/Controllers/Api/MarketController.js:36:23
(node:15265) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
(node:15265) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: you still need the catch.. let me update my answer from '...' to the catch

Comment: I'd like to add to this that it only worked for me once I added a callback to the line `jobQueries.push(jobSchema.find({u_sno:s.u.sno}));` so it became `jobQueries.push(jobSchema.find({u_sno:s.u.sno}), () => {});`

Comment: @LuisEgan Try to add mongoose.Promise = global.Promise where you connect to mongoose. Bluebird is an es5 Promise lib. but with later versions of node, you have Promise in global

Answer (score 6):

A nice elegant solution is to use the `cursor.eachAsync()` function. Credit to https://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-async-iterators-in-node-js.

> The eachAsync() function executes a (potentially async) function for
>   each document that the cursor returns. If that function returns a
>   promise, it will wait for that promise to resolve before getting the
>   next document. This is the easiest way to exhaust a cursor in
>   mongoose.

```
  // A cursor has a `.next()` function that returns a promise. The promise
  // will resolve to the next doc if there is one, or null if they are no
  // more results.
  const cursor = MyModel.find().sort({name: 1 }).cursor();

  let count = 0;
  console.log(new Date());
  await cursor.eachAsync(async function(doc) {
    // Wait 1 second before printing first doc, and 0.5 before printing 2nd
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000 - 500 * (count++)));
    console.log(new Date(), doc);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** which is synchronous and being called in an asynchronous fashion, that will give you wrong results.

You can use the aggregation framework and use **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** which performs a left outer join to another collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing.

So the same query can be done using a single aggregation pipeline as:

```
userSchema.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "jobs", /* underlying collection for jobSchema */
            "localField": "sno",
            "foreignField": "u_sno",
            "as": "jobs"
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, docs){
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(
        JSON.stringify({
            status: "success",
            message: "successfully done",
            data: docs
        })
    );
})
```

Comment: suggest for i need inner join like we need both result users and jos something one to one table

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: its 3.2 version

Comment: @chridam mongodb doesn't supports inner join, instead it supports only left outer join.